# setting element focus after ajax _partial refresh fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a partial element which contains inputs. I store the currently focused element id in a hidden input on the parent form.
After refreshing the partial element using an ajax call i want to reset the focus back to the previously selected element.
All of the functions in terms of storing and retrieving the element id work, as does the partial refresh and the data update called within that, however when i then go to set focus at the end nothing seems to happen.
please can someone give me an idea as to where i'm going wrong.

ps. i am using chrome for testing and the app is written using VS2022 and ASP.net Core 6

Below is the onChange code called to refresh the partial element and any logging

```
$(document).on('change', ".updateable", function (event) {
    //if (event.type === 'change') {
    //$(".updateable").change(function() {
    console.log("focusHolder.val - pre refresh " + $('#focusHolder').val());
    var subAgent = $('#subagentId').attr('value');
    var rowId = $(this).attr('rowID');

    var updatedField = $(this).attr("id").substring(0, $(this).attr("id").length - (rowId.length + 1));
    var updatedValue = $(this).val(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Rating/UpdateCurrentRates',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { subAgent_ID: subAgent, row_ID: rowId, fieldName: updatedField, newValue: updatedValue },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#newRates").html(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, exception) {
            //alert;
            return false;
        }
    })
        //    .done(function () {

        //    console.log("focused - done " + focused);
        //    var focused = $('#focusHolder').val();
        //    $(focused).focus();

        //})
        .always(function () {

            var focused = $('#focusHolder').val();
            console.log("focused - always " + focused);
$(focused).focus();

        });
    console.log("ajax call finished");

});
```

Comment: seems like you'd want var focused = $('#focusHolder')  Remove the .val()

Comment: Thanks for your response. #focusHolder just contains the name of the element i want to set focus to so i'm passing that val into a variable and then casting that as an object at the point i try to set focus.
I've also tried casting as an object separately but that didn't seem to work either:
            var focusedName = $('#focusHolder').val();
            $focused = $(focusedName);
            $focused.focus();

Comment: @pcalkins - you have just made me see the issue. I knew it would be something simple i was missing but just couldn't see it til responding to you. 
On writing the currently focused element name to the #focusHolder hidden field, it doesn't include the '#' symbol. Therefore when casting back it's never finding the id because it's missing the '#' in the id reference.

Comment: The "#" should be jQuery's way of specifying an ID attribute as locator. The id should just be "focusHolder". (make sure it's unique...)   You can do $('#' + yourID) if needed.